# java - SwingWorker doens't run when calling Thread.sleep() in EDT thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I am trying to create a program to solve quadratic equation and calculate the solving time. I have JButton that when i clicked it, the calculation will begin. My SwingWorker is for counting time, it will update time every 1 second. Because the calculation is fast, I call Thread.sleep() in JButton actionPerformed so i can see SwingWorker counting time, but when I call Thread.sleep(3000) in EDT thread, SwingWorker doesn't work but wait after the equation solving is finished to print out running time = 3s. How can i fix this so SwingWorker will update time every 1 second instead of printing out just 3s.

```
//SwingWorker for counting time
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Long> {

   private JLabel label;

   public Worker(JLabel label) {
      this.label = label;
   }

   @Override
   protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
      long i = System.currentTimeMillis();

      Timer SimpleTimer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener(){
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            publish(System.currentTimeMillis() - i);
         }
      });
      SimpleTimer.start();

      return  1; 
   }

    protected void process(List<Long> chunks) {

       for(long i : chunks) {
          label.setText("" + i);
       }
    }
}


//Solving quadratic function in JButton actionPerformed
private void solveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    int a, b, c;
    double x1, x2;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        a = Integer.parseInt(inputA.getText());
        b = Integer.parseInt(inputB.getText());
        c = Integer.parseInt(inputC.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Re-enter.");
        return;
    }
    Worker worker = new Worker(clock);
    worker.execute();

            try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    if(delta < 0) {
        result.setText(".");
    } else if(delta == 0) {
        result.setText("x1 = x2 = " + -b / 2 * a);
    } else {
        x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);

        result.setText("<html>x1 = " + x1 +  "<br>x2 = " + x2 + "</html>");
    }
}
```

I have found a solution now, i put the timer and the calculation code in a same thread class:

```
public class NewThread implements Runnable {

   private JLabel label, result;
   private int a, b, c;

   public NewThread(JLabel label, int a, int b, int c, JLabel result) {
      this.label = label;
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
      this.result = result;
   }
   @Override
   public void run() {
      double x1, x2;  

      long i = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener(){
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             label.setText("Thoi gian tinh toan: " + (Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() - i) / 1000) + " giay");
          }
      });

      timer.start();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (Exception e) {

   }

    double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    if(delta < 0) {
        result.setText("Phuong trinh vo nghiem.");
    } else if(delta == 0) {
        result.setText("Phuong trinh co nghiem kep x1 = x2 = " + -b / 2 * a);
    } else {
        x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);

        result.setText("<html>Phuong co 2 nghiem.<br>x1 = " + x1 +  "<br>x2 = " + x2 + "</html>");
    }

    timer.stop();

}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am frustrated with this. If you can just help me and then close this.

Comment: if you ise `sleep` or any other time consuming operation in the EDT, there will be no updates to the GUI since they are all run in the EDT (which is blocked). That is exactly the reason for having a`SwingWorker` - to separate the long running tasks from the GUI tasks. In other works the `sleep` and the calculation should go in a (second) `SwingWorker` (or just a simple Thread)

Comment: *"I am frustrated with this."* I cannot begin to express to you just how much **nobody** else cares. This is your problem to fix or become frustrated over, for everyone else, it is purely academic. If you want fast answers, listen careful to instructions and follow the advice offered. I decided not only to close this, but to down vote both questions. Edit the first to add an MCVE & I *might* withdraw that one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank  you i understand that. I have to go to work now. I promise i will edit both questions by tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My SwingWorker is for counting time, it will update time every 1 second.

If the only responsibility of this worker is to update a label with the elapsed time, then a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) is a better candidate to do it. Let the SwingWorker `doInBackground()` implementation do the heavy calculation and finally the `done()` implementation may just stop the timer and display the final results.

Do not call `Thread.sleep()` in the EDT because it will freeze the entire GUI event processing and you'll probably see just the final result without the intended periodic updates.

### Update

Adding just a simple snippet to start with:

```
public void startCalculation() {

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        AtomicInteger elapsedSeconds = new AtomicInteger();

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            label.setText(String.format("Elapsed time: %d seconds", elapsedSeconds.incrementAndGet()));
       }
    });

    SwingWorker<Integer, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Integer, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // do heavy stuff
            Thread.sleep(3000); // it is safe to "sleep" here because it's not executed in the EDT
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            timer.stop();
            // update the GUI with the results here if it's required
        }
    };

    timer.start();
    worker.execute();
}
```

Comment: But i can only use the button to fire everything. If i put the Swing Timer inside actionPerformed, it can't calculate running time of the solving part in actionPerformed

Comment: I think it's perfectly possible to start everything by clicking a single button, you only need to figure out how the pieces are connected. I've just added a very simple snippet to start with. @ThuanNguyen

Comment: Note 1: start the `timer` inside the `SwingWorker` (`doInBackgorund`) since it is also being stopped there (`done`). Note 2: it should be `return 42` [:-)